# Flutter fullscreen app. Getting rid of the blank white space at the bottom of the app on android

Tags: flutter, android-fullscreen, flutter-layout, android-navigation-bar

I used `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` to make my flutter app full screen.

The status bar is gone for good, but I get this white space at the bottom where the nav bar used to be.

[image]

Comment: Also, fullscreen_mode plugin has exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Aasiz how did you solve this problem? I am facing it now, please help.

Comment: Answers below are correct. just set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false in the scaffold widget.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to `false` on `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  appBar: new AppBar(),
);
```

Comment: @Rémi It does hide the bottom navigation bar but after screen is touched, navigation bar comes up again and stays forever. I know in Android, we can do `getWindow().setFlags(...)` but I was thinking of some way to handle it in flutter.

Answer (score 4):

this code work for me, thx

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
    )
 }
```

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding has been deprecated and now you have to use **resizeToAvoidBottomInset**

Updated code below:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used resizeToAvoidBottomPadding = false but sometimes there's white padding at where navigation bar is. It's inconsistent, sometime it's shown, sometimes it's not

Answer (score -2):

use SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); in your widget,it will work perfect:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // To make this screen full screen.
    // It will hide status bar and notch.
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    // full screen image for splash screen.
    return Container(
            child: new Image.asset('assets/splash.png', fit: BoxFit.fill));
      }
    }
```

and remember to import this

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```